# Error! Getting compile time error in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

Getting the compile time error. How can we solve this in cocoa app.

```
    ld: warning: directory not found for option '-/.../../../../24-09-09/branches/LeopardPlusErrorHandling/build/Debug'
    ld: warning: directory not found for option '-/.../../LeopardPlusErrorHandling/build/Debug'
    ld: warning: directory not found for option '-/../../../Downloads/BWToolkit'
    ld: warning: directory not found for option '-'-/.../../BWToolkit'
    ld: warning: ignoring file /../.../../../Connection.framework/Connection, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0xce 0xfa 0xed 0xfe 0x 7 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 0x 3 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 0x 6 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 ) which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): /..../Connection.framework/Connection
    ld: cannot link directly with /...../ImageIO.framework/ImageIO.  Link against the umbrella framework 'ApplicationServices.framework' instead. for architecture x86_64
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First, to be really correct that seems like a linker error. Anyway,seems you have passed some strange linker options and are trying to link to strange libraries? How do you pass what linker options?

Comment: Actually the projects contains above 50 class files and json files. So i am unable to find where i am getting this linker error.

Comment: I just think this seems like a strange linker option: "'-/.../../../../24-09-09/branches/LeopardPlusErrorHandling/build/Debug'", but it might be the error message that is a bit misleading.

Comment: How to solve this linker error. Any idea?

Comment: I would like to see the command line used to compile and link. You can get it from xcode (in Log Navigator).

Comment: I am runnning directly from xcode.

Comment: That does not mean you cannot see the command line? If you look in the Log navigator (to the left) you will find your builds. Open one and you can find the command line showing you how the build was done.

Comment: ld: cannot link directly with /...../ImageIO.framework/ImageIO.  Link against the umbrella framework 'ApplicationServices.framework' instead. for architecture x86_64.. This log i am getting.

Comment: If you open the log navigator you will find your recent builds and runs etc. Pick one of the failing builds and select it. In your editor you will find your build and the different steps. The command line for every step is available by clicking them in the editor.